# Strange behavior with inApp purchases

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, crash, in-app-purchase

I've got a very strange problem recently. I have a code which processes inApp purchases in my app. I haven't changed anything in the code for month and this week I got a crash when calling   the following method:

```
//
// call this before making a purchase
//
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
```

I've tried to perform bt command in gdb and got following:

```
#0  0x33adffdc in CFRetain ()
#1  0x31f5bdb6 in ___init_block_invoke_2 ()
#2  0x36e797ea in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#3  0x36e7965a in dispatch_barrier_sync_f$VARIANT$up ()
#4  0x36e7928e in dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$up ()
#5  0x36e79910 in dispatch_sync$VARIANT$up ()
#6  0x36e7b576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#7  0x31f5c706 in CPLoggingAddCustomLogFile ()
#8  0x320a2658 in __MCLoggingInitialize_block_invoke_1 ()
#9  0x36e7b576 in dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$up ()
#10 0x320a26a4 in MCLoggingInitialize ()
#11 0x320a3060 in -[MCProfileConnection _init] ()
#12 0x320a3764 in +[MCProfileConnection sharedConnection] ()
#13 0x31750764 in +[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] ()
#14 0x00037702 in -[InAppPay canMakePurchases] (self=0x44b1a0, _cmd=0x149c1e) at    /Users/lowfreq/Desktop/Projects/magazinereader/Archive/InAppPay.m:32
#15 0x00039444 in -[PreViewArchives Tap:] (self=0x46aba0, _cmd=0x149d03, sender=0x46f030) at /Users/lowfreq/Desktop/Projects/magazinereader/Archive/PreViewArchives.m:161
#16 0x33af1434 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#17 0x34c1f9ea in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#18 0x34c1f9a6 in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#19 0x34c1f984 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#20 0x34c1f6f4 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#21 0x34c2002c in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#22 0x34c1e50e in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#23 0x34c1df00 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#24 0x34c044ec in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#25 0x34c03d2c in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#26 0x3572edf2 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#27 0x33b6b552 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#28 0x33b6b4f4 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#29 0x33b6a342 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#30 0x33aed4dc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#31 0x33aed3a4 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#32 0x3572dfcc in GSEventRunModal ()
#33 0x34c32742 in UIApplicationMain ()
#34 0x00002364 in main (argc=1, argv=0x2fdffb38) at /Users/lowfreq/Desktop/Projects/magazinereader/main.m:14
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

What's going on?  I can't understand the reason why the code which worked for month without any problem now giving me a crash?
I've tried to rebuild provisioning profiles from scratch, reset my iPad but still no luck
Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: ok, I've got what was the problem. The problem was caused by name of app which has been written with russian letters. Once I added a first space in app name - the problem is gone. Seems to like an ugly bug in SDK itself.

Comment: Mystery, but it works! Thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are trying for `SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments` try both in device and simulator.. if it crashes in both.. then it got to be code error..then post the code.

Comment: I tried it everywhere... but no luck at all..         self.inAppPay = [[InAppPay alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self.inAppPay];
   self.inAppPay.preViewArchives = self;
   if ([inAppPay canMakePurchases]== YES) {
    button.enabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"PAY TRUE");
    [self.inAppPay purchaseProUpgrade:idProducts];
   }else {NSLog(@"PAY FAIL");}

Comment: it crashes on both device and simulator?

Comment: yes. it crashes on both! and what's really funny it doesn't crash per se. it just gets stuck forever on canMakePayment call

Comment: try BOOL temp =[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]; and then Nslog it and then return..then put breakpoints in the function and check where it gets stuck,

Comment: I tried to change canMakePayent call to simply returning YES but then - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions method returns unknown transaction.transactionState. it is not one of values defined in SKPaymentTransaction.h

Comment: that is a different thing.. well is your app live.? why are you on a  project that you didn't touch in a month..will give me more info

Comment: BOOL temp=NO;
    temp =[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
    NSLog(temp);
    return temp;  it gets stuck on second line and if I press continue in debugger app crashes silently without any warning.

Comment: the app is live and very well used. but the code which handles iAP has not been touched for month since it is working and no need to change what;s working. something is happened and i can't get what

Comment: remove storekit framework and relink and try again..clean your project.. .that is the only recommendation i can give now

Comment: hmm i noticed that in simulator it doesn't crash. it just returns NO. always. As far as I know, simulator doesn't support IAP, so it does;t crash. After relinking StoreKit - the same problem on iPad.

Comment: try to change parental control settings in the device and then try again.. or switch off the device and start again..otherwise go to developer forums on apple and see the section of in app purchase to check if there is a problem that is actually taking place from apple side

Comment: the real problem was that app has cyrillic name. once i added a space at beginning of app name - voila!